# professional code template for Python project - include Modules, Packages, Unit Test, API / Help - IDE

Tags: python, unit-testing, templates, ide

I'm trying to find an IDE that can build Python code templates for me to get started with a large Python project. It should include typical professional / production looking code with Python 3 style, Unit Testing, API/Documentation, Code Review, Packages / Modules, Errors / Exceptions etc etc

In Visual Studio I can build this in .NET quickly ... the Project Wizards build this quickly ... but am struggling to find an IDE that can do something similar for Python.

Any suggestion or push in the right direction is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few but personally I'm a fan of [WingWare](http://www.wingware.com/). Partly because I really like the layout of it, but also I got a [free pro license for being a student](https://wingware.com/store/free)

Comment: thanks ... what are the others? I would like to compare as well

Answer (score 0):

In python world, IDE usually doesn't create skeleton project. There's a tool called cookiecutter, it can be used to create python skeleton project from template.

The popular python template is [cookiecutter-pypackage)(https://github.com/audreyfeldroy/cookiecutter-pypackage), which earns 3k stars. The skeleton project will include make file/setup tools, unittest, docs<sphinix), tox, pytest, lint tools, travis, code coverage and etc.

If you'd like project build with the following tools, then ppw(Python Project Wizard) is what you want:

1. poetry
2. mkdocs
3. github CI/CD (github workflow)
4. github pages for documentation
5. tox, pre-commit hooks, flake8, black, codecov, pytest,...
6. release notes auto generation

ppw is a python package which can be installed with:

```
pip install ppw
```